# Selecting doctests with attributes/tags in nosetest

Tags: python, nose, doctest

I have a project containing both doctests and Unittest based tests that are run using nosetest.

Since some of the tests are slow and relies on an external database, I want to use [tagging](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/attrib.html) to select which tests to run. This is no problems with the Unittests, I simply use the `attr` decorator, but when I come to the doctests I can't seem to find a syntax for tagging.

In conclution: Is it possible to add attributes to doctests?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience in nosetest generally or in tagging specifically, but there is a way to get a doctest as a `unittest.TestSuite` using [doctest.DocTestSuite](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html#doctest.DocTestSuite). So perhaps you can use it to convert your `doctest` to `testsuite` and then add the tagging as you would for a regular `unittest`.